# Пропадает слайдер carouFredSel в Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, slider

Есть слайдер carouFredSel на всю ширину страницы, объединил его с fancybox, в Google Chrome он не отображается, при перезагрузке иногда показывается, в Mozilla Firefox отображается стабильно.

Скрины из Mozilla Firefox:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Скрин из Mozilla Firefox]

Скрин из Google Chrome:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Набор скриптов такой:

```
<!-- script -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="js/setting.js"></script>
```

Пробовал отключить fancybox, пробовал убрать весь остальной код и оставить только слайдер - не помогло.

Сам сайт: http://divasad.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй два варианта:

- Загружать fancybox перед слайдером:

```
<script src="js/fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script src="js/setting.js">
```

- Для класса fancybox-overlay попробуй задать не display: none - display: block , а что-нибудь вроде visibility или opacity + z-index

"попап" классы в fancybox изначально имеют display: none => не участвуют в разметке и возможно из за этого слайдер не отображается